# Conjugacy class of an element in $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I need help to answer the following problem:

Let $n\ge 3$, $\sigma\in A_n$, $cl_{S_n}(\sigma)$ be the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ in $S_n$ and $cl_{A_n}(\sigma)$ be the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ in $A_n$.

> Show that if $C_{S_n}(\sigma)\not\subset A_n$ then $cl_{A_n}(\sigma)=cl_{S_n}(\sigma)$

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any progress? I'd figure out what's got to be a subset/subgroup of what, then see what orbit-stabilizer has to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $|cl_{S_n}(\sigma)| = [S_n:C_{S_n}(\sigma)]$ and $|cl_{A_n}(\sigma)| = [A_n:C_{A_n}(\sigma)]$. Now we have that $C_{A_n}(\sigma)$ is a proper subgroup of $C_{S_n}(\sigma)$, as $C_{S_n}(\sigma) \not \subset A_n$. So we have that $[C_{S_n}(\sigma):C_{A_n}(\sigma)] \ge 2$. Hence

$$\frac{|cl_{S_n}(\sigma)|}{|cl_{A_n}(\sigma)|} = \frac{[S_n:C_{S_n}(\sigma)]}{[A_n:C_{A_n}(\sigma)]} = \frac{[S_n:A_n]}{[C_{S_n}(\sigma):C_{A_n}(\sigma)]} \le \frac{2}{2} = 1$$

But also trivially $cl_{A_n}(\sigma) \subset cl_{S_n}(\sigma)$, so we must have that $|cl_{S_n}(\sigma)| = |cl_{A_n}(\sigma)|$. Hence $cl_{S_n}(\sigma) = cl_{A_n}(\sigma)$.

Comment: And how to prove that if $C_{S_n}(\sigma)\subset A_n$ then $cl_{S_n}(\sigma)=cl_{A_n}(\sigma)\coprod cl_{A_n}(\tilde{\sigma)}$ where $\tilde{\sigma}=\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ with $\tau\in A_n\backslash S_n$?

Comment: @siwar Could you please edit, as there's something wrong with the MathJax. On the other side it look like a completely different questions. Don't you think it would be better to postit as a separate question?

Comment: i post it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625545/conjugacy-class-in-a-n

Comment: @siwar I will try to answer that question there, if you have anything to ask about my answer in particular you can ask it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan! your answer is detailed and it will help me with my revision for my test

Comment: @siwar You're welcome! Anyway i would advise you to try to solve the problems on your own, which will help you understand the topics significantly. Posting your effort and where you encounter the problem will help you and us locate where you struggle and you can focus on that area specifically.

Comment: for the other question i tried to use definitions but i don't manage to answer

Comment: @siwar Post everything you tried in that question, not here :)